# Mouse manipulation on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I asked a similar question a few weeks back but it failed to attract an answer but this is a more open query (it was a couple of days before the holidays though).  Previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518559/consuming-osx-mouse-trackpad-events-with-an-event-tap)

Is there any way to prevent mouse movement or clicks being passed to whatever app is in the foreground, or give the impression that it is.  I'm particularly interested in preventing the mouse being moved by the trackpad or magicpad.

I basically want the user to perform a gesture on the magicpad, disable the mouse functionality/system gestures, monitor/react to further gestures on the pad and at some point re-instate the mouse functionality.   The closest I have come to keep warping the mouse cursor back to where it was on activation for each mouse move event, but this causes the mouse to flitter back and forth which is very distracting.  I have managed to hide the cursor globally but the mouse is still moving and clicks occurring, which while you can't see it can be very distracting confusing when the app underneath reacts to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by Graham's comment on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518559/consuming-osx-mouse-trackpad-events-with-an-event-tap)

Answer (score 3):

Are you manipulating your own application's events, or other applications?

Would the **CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition()** function be helpful in eliminating the flickering mouse?

```
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(false);
...
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true);
```

From Apple's Quartz Display Services Programming - [Controlling the Mouse Cursor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/MouseCursor.html)

Comment: I'm trying to do it for all other apps, my app is going to be running as an agent, I believe this only works for the application?

Comment: @vickirk, I am not sure how this will behave if called by an agent.