# Programmatically Disable Mouse & keyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix, keyboard, mouse

I would like to programmatically disable mouse & keyboard input temporarily on a mac (using Objective C/C/Unix) & then reenable them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518559/consuming-osx-mouse-trackpad-events-with-an-event-tap

Comment: Another solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785630/modify-nsevent-to-send-a-different-key-than-the-one-that-was-pressed/5785895#5785895

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made a small open source application that allows you to selectively disable keyboards with the `CGEventTap` function from OS X.  It is inside the Carbon Framework, but based on CoreFoundation, so it also works on Lion.
As an example you can try my open SourceApp [MultiLayout, available here on GitHub](https://github.com/FeeJai/MultiLayout).

Basically what you need to do if you want to do it yourself is:

To use it, you need to add the Carbon Framework:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
```

Then create an event tap like this:

```
void tap_keyboard(void) {
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;

    CGEventMask mask = kCGEventMaskForAllEvents;
    //CGEventMask mask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyUp) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown);

    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, mask, myCGEventCallback, NULL);

    if (!eventTap) { 
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create event tap!");
        exit(1);
    }

    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

    CFRelease(eventTap);
    CFRelease(runLoopSource);

}
```

To interrupt the events when necessary, use this snippet:

```
bool dontForwardTap = false;

CGEventRef myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {


    //NSLog(@"Event Tap: %d", (int) CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode));

    if (dontForwardTap)
        return nil;
    else
        return event;
}
```

Just set the boolean `dontForwardTap` to true, and the events will be stopped.